# How to get data inside a Lansa grid using user32 SendMessage

Tags: lansa

We are automating an Windows application built with Lansa technology. The application is having grids for which we are facing issues to get data or perform actions on as Inspect.exe is not showing any data inside those grids.
Can anyone please help how to use user32 dll SendMessage to retrieve information for Lansa grid.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try asking on the LANSA forums. That is where most of the LANSA folks hang out.

https://forum.developer.lansa.com/